# placeholderText in TextFields is not shown when inputMask is used

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but when I set an input mask in a `TextField` with a `placeholderText`, this placeholder is not shown.

When this happens, we see the `TextField` empty with no text. In the next example, `textField1` shows only a dot (.) which is part of the `inputMask`.

I'm working with Qt 5.5.0. This behaviour can be checked using the following example.

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600

    TextField {
        id: textField1
        placeholderText: "0.0"
        inputMask: "999.99"
    }

    TextField {
        id: textField2
        anchors.top: textField1.bottom
        placeholderText: "0.0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed it doesn't work with an `inputMask`. If you define an `inputMask`, the field is not empty when it's created, so the `placeholderText` does not activate. I'm not sure it can be considered a bug (for me it is), but if not I think it should be documented.

The buggiest thing is that even with nothing but numbers in the `inputMask`, the field is still initialized with blanks.

NB in your case you can maybe use a validator or `inputMethodHints` flags instead.

```
TextField {
    id: textField1
    placeholderText: "0.0"
    validator: DoubleValidator { top: 999; decimals: 2; }
}
```

Comment: @Tarod You're welcome. NB I'm not sure that the "top" property works for the double validator, if it does not, you've also `maximumLength` as an alternative.

Comment: Actually if there is nothing but numbers in the inputMask, the placeHolderText DOES appear (QtQuick.Controls 1.2)

Comment: @Yoann Could you please give me an example? I've just tested `placeholderText: "99"` and `inputMask: "99"` and the `TextField` appears with blanks.

Comment: @Yoann I've just tested with QtQuick.Controls 1.4, the latest version, and it doesn't (inputMask = 9999).

Comment: There seems to be a regression since it works well with QtQuick.Controls 1.2. With placeholderText: "0.0" and  inputMask: "999", the placeHolderText is correctly displayed